# How to parse "which was especially humiliating because everyone was talking about it the next morning"?

Tags: syntactic-analysis

- Cara’s mother berated her in front of the entire basketball team, which was especially humiliating because everyone was talking about it the next morning.

Is the relative clause ‘which was especially humiliating because everyone was talking about it the next morning’ modifying the independent clause ‘Cara’s mother berated her in front of the entire basketball team’?

Comment: Don't you have any idea at all?

Comment: You'll need to give us a hint of what about it is giving you problems.

Comment: What part of it do you find hard to parse?

Comment: The "relative clause" starting with ***which*** refers back to *the entire preceding statement* - more precisely, to the "fact" asserted in the earlier clause *(**the fact that** Cara's mother berated her in front of the entire basketball team)*. That fact / act was humiliating, ***because of*** the reason as specified. It would be conceptually the same if you ended that first assertion with a period, and started the next one with ***This** (fact / act) was humiliating...*

Comment: Semantically, [Cara’s mother berated her in front of the entire basketball team] and [everyone was talking about it the next morning] are the twin reasons why the _whole process_ was 'especially humiliating'.  This is perhaps what caused the confusion. Grammatical analysis and semantics don't always correspond Perhaps they should.

Answer (score 1):

One way to parse is to rearrange or separate clauses, and see events on a timeline. See if this helps:

1) Cara's mother berated her in front of the entire basketball team.
2) Everyone was talking about it the next morning. 
3) That (#2) was especially humiliating (for Cara).

Comment: No, 3 refers to 1, not 2.

Answer (score 1):

> Cara’s mother berated her in front of the entire basketball team, which was especially humiliating because everyone was talking about it the next morning.

Cara’s mother *–subject*

berated *– verb*

her *– object*

in front of the entire basketball team, *- adverbial phrase modifying “berated”*

which was especially humiliating *– subordinate conjunctive relative clause whose referent is the main clause* (cf "and that was especially humiliating")

because everyone was talking about it the next morning. *- Subordinate clause of reason modifying “humiliating".*